# JQuery function that create tables with some properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var nr = 0;
  $("#raspuns").text(nr);
  $("#t1 #e1").on({
    mouseover: function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "green");
    },
    click: function() {
      $(this).off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e4").off('mouseleave');
      $(this).off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('mouseover');
      $(this).off('click');
      $("#t1 #e4").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('click');
      nr = 1;
      $("#raspuns").text(nr);
    }
  });

  $("#t1 #e2").on({
    mouseover: function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
      $("#t1 #e1").css("background-color", "yellow");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "green");
      $("#t1 #e1").css("background-color", "green");
    },
    click: function() {
      $(this).off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e4").off('mouseleave');
      $(this).off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e4").off('mouseover');
      $(this).off('click');
      $("#t1 #e4").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('click');
      nr = 2;
      $("#raspuns").text(nr);
    }
  });
  $("#t1 #e3").on({
    mouseover: function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
      $("#t1 #e1").css("background-color", "yellow");
      $("#t1 #e2").css("background-color", "yellow");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "green");
      $("#t1 #e1").css("background-color", "green");
      $("#t1 #e2").css("background-color", "green");
    },
    click: function() {
      $(this).off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e4").off('mouseleave');
      $(this).off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e4").off('mouseover');
      $(this).off('click');
      $("#t1 #e4").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('click');
      nr = 3;
      $("#raspuns").text(nr);
    }
  });
  $("#t1 #e4").on({
    mouseover: function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
      $("#t1 #e1").css("background-color", "yellow");
      $("#t1 #e2").css("background-color", "yellow");
      $("#t1 #e3").css("background-color", "yellow");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "green");
      $("#t1 #e1").css("background-color", "green");
      $("#t1 #e2").css("background-color", "green");
      $("#t1 #e3").css("background-color", "green");
    },
    click: function() {
      $(this).off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('mouseleave');
      $(this).off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('mouseover');
      $(this).off('click');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('click');
      nr = 4;
      $("#raspuns").text(nr);
    }
  });
  $("#t1 #e5").on({
    mouseover: function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
      $("#t1 #e1").css("background-color", "yellow");
      $("#t1 #e2").css("background-color", "yellow");
      $("#t1 #e3").css("background-color", "yellow");
      $("#t1 #e4").css("background-color", "yellow");
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "green");
      $("#t1 #e1").css("background-color", "green");
      $("#t1 #e2").css("background-color", "green");
      $("#t1 #e3").css("background-color", "green");
      $("#t1 #e4").css("background-color", "green");
    },
    click: function() {
      $(this).off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('mouseleave');
      $("#t1 #e4").off('mouseleave');
      $(this).off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('mouseover');
      $("#t1 #e4").off('mouseover');
      $(this).off('click');
      $("#t1 #e1").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e2").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e3").off('click');
      $("#t1 #e5").off('click');
      nr = 5;
      $("#raspuns").text(nr);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}
table {
  border-color: black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body style="background-color : #90C3D4">
  <table id="t1" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="e1"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="e2"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="e3"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="e4"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="e5"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p id="raspuns"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Hello guys, I did a selector that can select some parts of the table, now I want to make a function that makes 5 table with a random number of lines (ex : 5 tables with 4 lines),and if we selected from third table some elements then tables 1 and 2 automatically selects and so on, [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xt9d.jpg)

give me some ideas or some code. Thank You.

Comment: Unrelated to what you're asking, are you aware that `$("#e1, #e2, #e3, #e4").off('mouseleave');` does the job of the four separate lines of code you currently have to take `mouseleave` off those elements? (And the rest of your long function could be similarly simplified for the other events. Actually with appropriate classes you wouldn't need separate `.on()` handlers either, but I don't have time to explain that now.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As someone commented, you can use multiple jQuery selectors in the same line, because you use the same action for all:

```
$("#e1, #e2, #e3, #e4").off('mouseleave');
```

Also if you want to remove all events, you can use without parameters and it will remove all events :

```
$("#e1, #e2, #e3, #e4, #t1").off();
```

Here it is how you can handle multiple jQuery elements on a single action :

```
var createLines = function(table, randomNumber) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= randomNumber; i++) {
        $('<tr>')
            .addClass('row' + i)
            .appendTo(table)
            .attr('isSelected', 'no')
            .click(clickFunction)
    }
};

var createTables = function(randomNumber) {
    var table = $('<table>');

    createLines(table, randomNumber);
    table.appendTo('body');
};

var clickFunction = function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var elClass = $el.attr('class');
    var isSelected = $el.attr('isSelected');

    if (isSelected === 'yes') {
        $('.' + elClass).css('background', 'white');
        $el.attr('isSelected', 'no');
    } else {
        $('.' + elClass).css('background', 'yellow');
        $el.attr('isSelected', 'yes');
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    // 1 to 10
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        createTables(randomNumber);
    }
});
```

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/1bpmox78/